# Erro Ajax no console no envio do formulário

Tags: jquery

Está retornando esse erro no console quando envio um formulário com o Ajax

```
An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.
empresas_cadastrar.php:1 An invalid form control with name='bairro1' is not focusable.
empresas_cadastrar.php:1 An invalid form control with name='bairro3' is not focusable.
empresas_cadastrar.php:1 An invalid form control with name='bairro4' is not focusable.
empresas_cadastrar.php:1 An invalid form control with name='bairro5' is not focusable.
empresas_cadastrar.php:1 An invalid form control with name='bairro19' is not focusable.
```

Esses Ids dos erros name='bairro...' vem de um jquery, com o código abaixo

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change', '#sectionChooser', function(){
        var myID = $(this).val();
        $('.panel').each(function(){
            //var form_data= new FormData('.panel');
            myID === $(this).attr('id') ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
            console.log("ok");
        });
    })




    $(document).on('change', '[name^="bairro"]', function(){ 

       var bairroID = $(this).val();
            console.log("ok");

            if(bairroID){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'ajax_data2.php',
                    data:'bairro_id='+bairroID,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#rua[name^="rua"]').html(html);

                    }
                }); 
            }else{
                $('#rua').html('<option value="">Select bairro first</option>');

            }
        });

    });
```

esse é o código para o envio dos valores dos campos digitados

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#form_cadastros_empresa").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'form_cadastro.php',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('#form_cadastros_empresa').css("opacity",".5");
            },
            success: function(msg){
                $('.resultado_form_cadastros_empresa').html('');
                if(msg == 'ok'){
                    $('#form_cadastros_empresa')[0].reset();
                    $('.resultado_form_cadastros_empresa').html('<span style="font-size:18px;color:#34A853">Form data submitted successfully.</span>');
                }else{
                    $('.resultado_form_cadastros_empresa').html('<span style="font-size:18px;color:#EA4335">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                }
                $('#form_cadastros_empresa').css("opacity","");
                $(".submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    });


});
```

Como faria para resolver esse problema do erro?

Html

```
<div class="resultado_form_cadastros_empresa"></div>
<form method="post" action="javascript:;" id="form_cadastros_empresa" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="padding-left: 50px;">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="Numero">Usuário</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeUsuario" placeholder="Usuário">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="Complemento">Senha</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="senha" placeholder="Senha">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="Nome">Categoria</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="categoria" id="categoria" required>
                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                <?php //Open a new connection to the MySQL server $mysqli=n ew mysqli( xxx); //Output any connection error if ($mysqli->connect_error) { die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error); } //MySqli Select Query $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM categorias"); while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { echo '
                <option value="'.$row[" id "].'">'.utf8_encode($row["nome_categoria"]).'</option>'; } // Frees the memory associated with a result $results->free(); // close connection $mysqli->close(); ?></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="SobreNome">Subcategoria</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="subcategoria" id="subcategoria" required></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <label for="Nome">Nome da Empresa</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nome" placeholder="Nome" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="funcionamento">Horário de Funcionamento</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="funcionamento" placeholder="Horário de Funcionamento">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="descricao">Descrição da Empresa</label>
            <textarea rows="20" cols="50" id="descricao" placeholder="Descrição da Empresa"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="Site">Site</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Site" placeholder="Site">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="Facebook">Facebook</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Facebook" placeholder="Facebook">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="Intsagram">Instagram</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Instagram" placeholder="Intsagram">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="Twitter">Twitter</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Twitter" placeholder="Twitter">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="Planos">Planos</label>
            <select name="Planos" id="sectionChooser" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                <?php //Open a new connection to the MySQL server $mysqli=n ew mysqli( xxx); //Output any connection error if ($mysqli->connect_error) { die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error); } //MySqli Select Query $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM planos"); while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { echo '
                <option value="'.$row[" id "].'">'.utf8_encode($row["nome_plano"]).'</option>'; } // Frees the memory associated with a result $results->free(); // close connection $mysqli->close(); ?></select>
            <?php //Open a new connection to the MySQL server $mysqli=n ew mysqli( xxx); //Output any connection error if ($mysqli->connect_error) { die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error); } //MySqli Select Query $results_panos_2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM planos"); while($row_planos_2 = $results_panos_2->fetch_assoc()) {;?>
            <div class="panel" id="<? echo $row_planos_2[" id "];?>">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label><b><? echo utf8_encode($row_planos_2["nome_plano"]).'';?></b>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <? if (($row_planos_2[ "endereco_buscaiuva"]=="1" )){?>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <label for="endereco_buscauiva">Endereço Buscauiva</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endereco_buscauiva" placeholder="http://buscaiuva.com.br/NomeDaEmpresa" required>
                        </div>
                        <?}?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <? if (($row_planos_2[ "logomarca"]=="1" )){?>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <label for="Logomarca">Logomarca</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="Logomarca">
                        </div>
                        <? } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <? if (($row_planos_2[ "banner1"]=="1" )){?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="imagem1">Imagem banner 1</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="imagem1">
                        </div>
                        <? }?>
                        <? if (($row_planos_2[ "banner2"]=="1" )){?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="imagem2">Imagem banner 2</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="imagem2">
                        </div>
                        <? }?>
                        <? if (($row_planos_2[ "banner3"]=="1" )){?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="imagem3">Imagem banner 3</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="imagem3">
                        </div>
                        <? }?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <? if (($row_planos_2[ "telefone1"]=="1" )){?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="Telefone1">Telefone 1</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Telefone1" placeholder="Telefone 1" required>
                        </div>
                        <? }?>
                        <? if (($row_planos_2[ "telefone2"]=="1" )){?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="Telefone2">Telefone 2</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Telefone2" placeholder="Telefone 2">
                        </div>
                        <? }?>
                        <? if (($row_planos_2[ "telefone3"]=="1" )){?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="Telefone3">Telefone 3</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Telefone3" placeholder="Telefone 3">
                        </div>
                        <? }?>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <? if (($row_planos_2[ "endereco_empresa"]=="1" )){?>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="Bairro">Bairro</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="bairro<? echo $row_planos_2[" id "];?>" id="bairro<? echo $row_planos_2[" id "];?>" required>
                                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                                <?php //Open a new connection to the MySQL server $mysqli=n ew mysqli( xxx); //Output any connection error if ($mysqli->connect_error) { die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error); } //MySqli Select Query $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM bairro"); while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { echo '
                                <option value="'.$row[" id "].'">'.utf8_encode($row["bairro"]).'</option>'; } // Frees the memory associated with a result $results->free(); // close connection $mysqli->close(); ?></select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="Rua">Rua</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="rua<? echo $i++;?>" id="rua" required></select>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="Numero">Número</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Numero" placeholder="Número">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="Complemento">Complemento</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Complemento" placeholder="Complemento">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="CEP">CEP</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CEP" placeholder="CEP">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <? }?>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <? if (($row_planos_2[ "palavras_chave"]=="1" )){?>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="palavras_chave">Palavras-chave</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="palavras_chave" placeholder="Palavras-chave">
                        </div>
                        <? }?>
                        <? if (($row_planos_2[ "marcas"]=="1" )){?>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="marcas">Marcas</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="marcas" placeholder="Maras">
                        </div>
                        <? }?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <? if (($row_planos_2[ "blocos"]=="1" )){?>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 " style="margin-top:20px;">
                            <p>Tipo do Banner</p>
                            <select class="form-control" id="blocos">
                                <option value="nenhum_tipo">Nenhum</option>
                                <option value="Bloco_1">Bloco 1</option>
                                <option value="Bloco_2">Bloco 2</option>
                                <option value="Bloco_3">Bloco 3</option>
                                <option value="Bloco_4">Bloco 4</option>
                                <option value="Bloco_5">Bloco 5</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top:20px;">
                            <p>Aparecer por</p>
                            <select class="form-control" id="banner_tempo">
                                <option value="8_segundos">8 segundos</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <? }?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <? } // Frees the memory associated with a result $results_panos_2->free(); // close connection $mysqli->close(); ?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-check" style="margin-top: 40px;text-align: center;">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="plano_congelado">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="plano_congelado">Plano Congelado</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="cadastros_empresa" placeholder="cadastros_empresa" value="cadastros_empresa">
    <button type="submit" class="submitBtn">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Como está a página que recebe os dados enviados pelo Ajax e faz o retorno?

Answer (score -1):

No ajax, ao invés de usar `new FormData()`, utilize `$( this ).serialize()`.

Não tenho certeza se o `this` está se referenciando ao formulário, mas caso dê problema, tente `$( self ).serialize()`, sendo que você deverá criar a `var self = this;` antes do ajax.

Comment: Não vai funcionar, ele está utilizando o formulário para *upload*. O `jQuery.serialize` **não** funciona para isto.

Comment: nao funcionaou, estou usando o upload de arquivos